# California PLSS Quarter and Quarter Quarter Section Layers

Tags: arcgis-online, united-states, plss

I am trying to find the **quarter** section and **quarter-quarter** section layers for the PLSS layers of the state of California. I have the township & range and also the section layers but was unable to locate the quarter and quarter quarter section layers on ArcGIS Online and other online resources.

Comment: This doesn't meet your needs?  [BLM NV PLSS (CADNSDI Version 2) Intersected Polygon - data.doi.gov](https://data.doi.gov/dataset/blm-nv-plss-cadnsdi-version-2-intersected-polygon)

Comment: Or for online use:  [BLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI (MapServer)](https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastral/BLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI/MapServer)

Comment: @bixb0012 That is exactly what I am looking for I saw your Nevada comment and looked for California. Thank you very much kind stranger.